# Implement a custom comparator for my PriorityQueue

Tags: java, heap, comparator, priority-queue

I'm trying to solve the following leetcode problem:

Given a sorted array, two integers k and x, find the k closest elements to x in the array. The result should also be sorted in ascending order. If there is a tie, the smaller elements are always preferred.

Example 1:
Input: [1,2,3,4,5], k=4, x=3

Output: [1,2,3,4]

Example 2:
Input: [1,2,3,4,5], k=4, x=-1

Output: [1,2,3,4]

My incorrect solution for now is the following:

```
class Solution {
    public List<Integer> findClosestElements(int[] arr, int k, int x) {
        PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(arr.length, (a,b) -> a == b ? a - b : Math.abs(a-x) - Math.abs(b-x));

       for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
           pq.add(arr[i]);

       }



        ArrayList ints = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i=0;i<k;i++) {
            ints.add(pq.poll());


        }
        return ints;
    }
}
```

The problem is with the comparator I'm passing to the constructor. The idea is that I want my comparator to sort the integers with respect to the minimum distance between any integer i and the input `x` and then poll `k` elements from the queue. How can I impelement a comparator function that sorts the elements that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take advantage of the default `Integer.compare` method. Basically what you want is to first check the compare of the absolute difference, and if its a tie do a normal compare.

```
static int compare(int x, int a, int b) {
    int comp = Integer.compare(Math.abs(a - x), Math.abs(b - x));
    if (comp == 0) {
        return Integer.compare(a, b);
    }
    return comp;
}
```

This makes it pretty clean to write the actual priority queue implementation

```
static List<Integer> findClosestElements(int[] arr, int k, int x) {
    PriorityQueue<Integer> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(
        arr.length, (a,b) -> compare(x, a, b));
    Arrays.stream(arr).forEach(queue::add);
    return queue.stream().limit(k).sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Integer.compare simplifies it a lot.

Comment: @Tarun absolutely. I find it's so easy to mess up compares (whether you need a `-1` or `1`) that I always opt to just calling a builtin. Saves your code from lots of bugs at the expense of the extra method call. Would only roll manually if it was a super tight loop.

Answer (score 0):

In your implementation, you are not checking for the scenario where the distance of two integers is same from X.
Following Comparator implementation would give correct result:

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(arr.length, 
                (a,b) -> {
                    int comp = Integer.compare(Math.abs(a - x), Math.abs(b - x));
                    if(comp==0) {return Integer.compare(a, b);}
                    return comp;
                });
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you! any chance you can explain how the comparator return value from the comparator is actually used to insert the element into the heap? Meaning what happens when the return value is -1 vs 1 vs 0?

Comment: @SaifAbuhashish The result of comparator (1,-1,0) determines which of the two elements is greater than the other. In the above example, +1 means a>b, -1 means b>a and 0 means a==b. This result of comparator helps priorityQueue to order the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Here, the problem is not with your priority queue but we need two results with different ordering formats. Your queue will give top K elements but that will never be in ascending order as it orders element with respect to distance from "X", So for given X=4, elements 3 and 5 both are at the same level so your result will have data like [4,3,5].

Better to have separate sort for result list.

do `Collections.sort(ints);` and return the result.

Answer (score -2):

```
Queue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>((a,b)->(Math.abs(a-x)<Math.abs(b-x))?1:-1);
```